# how to convert RealmList<T> to RealmResults<T>

Tags: java, android, realm

I am working on realm database and want to convert RealmList to RealmResults. The realmlist is attribute of realm object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use query on your list :

```java
class MyObject extends RealmObject {

    RealmList<MySubObject> subObjects;
}

...

myObject.subObjects.where().findAll(); //returns a RealmResults

//you can query your list like
myObject.subObjects
     .where()
     .equalTo("status", "done")
     .findAll(); //you can use sort, findFirst etc
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
RealmResults<T> results = realmList.where().findAll();
```

Please note that this only works on ***managed*** RealmList.